# Servidor Rest Spring identificando um ponto como expressão regular

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

Tenho um serviço Rest com o seguinte método:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/usuario/{login}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> usuario(@PathVariable("login") String login, HttpServletRequest request) {
        User user = userService.buscarPorNickname(login);
        InputStream is = null;
        if (user != null) {
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(user.getPicture().getCaminho());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (is == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG).body(new InputStreamResource(is));
        }
    }
```

Quando o nome de usuário possui um ponto, o servidor entende como uma expressão regular e me retorna um arquivo vazio. Como contornar isso?

Comment: No caso o método buscarPorNickname que não retorna o usuário? Se sim poste o código deste método

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso queira obter o formato completo, deve utilizar a expressão regular:

/somepath/{variable:.+} no seu caso "/usuario/{login:.+}"

Resultados que obterá:

/somepath/param dará origem a uma variável com valor "param"
/somepath/param.json dará origem a uma variável com valor "param.json"
/somepath/param.xml dará origem a uma variável com valor "param.xml"
/somepath/param.anything dará origem a uma variável com valor "param.anything"
/somepath/param.value.json dará origem a uma variável com valor "param.value.json"

Portanto ficaria assim:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/usuario/{login:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> usuario(@PathVariable("login") String login, HttpServletRequest request) {
    User user = userService.buscarPorNickname(login);
    InputStream is = null;
    if (user != null) {
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(user.getPicture().getCaminho());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (is == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG).body(new InputStreamResource(is));
    }
}
```

Poderia reinventar a roda, mas resposta obtida directamente da versão original do [StackOverflow EN - Spring MVC @PathVariable with dot (.) is getting truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated)

Caso seja possível existir mais do que um ponto, a expressão seria:
/somepath/{variable:.`*`} no seu caso "/usuario/{login:.`*`}"

Comment: Já tinha obtido essa resposta nesse link: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-pathvariable-dot-get-truncated/                                                Porém, o acrécimo da informação à respeito de mais pontos, foi muito boa. Muito obrigado!